# Is there an alternative to using Rails.env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

In my controller, I have a section that creates an email and sends it out, but I want that feature to be only available on production.

```
email = PortalEmail.new(params[:portal][:email]) if Rails.env.production? && PortalEmail.app_or_site?(@object)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps within the configuration/environments folder?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Testing `Rails.env.production?` is the best and most concise way to conditionally execute code only in your production environment.

That said, you should remove the conditional code from your controller and instead configure a fake MTA to receive email outside of the production environment. For example, [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) provides a fake MTA which will "catch" any mail sent by your development environment and hold on to it, for you to inspect in their web-based UI.

It's typically better to configure your app to use fake dependencies in development, than to litter your code with conditional environment checks.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use flags set in application.rb like this:

```
# application.rb
config.can_send_mail = false

# production.rb
config.can_send_mail = true
```

Then use

```
email = PortalEmail.new(params[:portal][:email]) if Rails.application.config.can_send_mail && PortalEmail.app_or_site?(@object)
```

to avoid littering my app with references to the environment. This makes it easier when you later add a new environment (like a staging environment) that needs to send email too.

Comment: Perfect solution. I am so grateful to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) to preview emails in browser when running in development mode.

Just add it under the development group and you can configure it like this:

```
# config/environments/development.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

And you won't need that conditional anymore.